# Call a Hyperlink in my Browser and want, that it automatically press a button on the Website

Tags: url, browser, hyperlink

I want to make a link from another website that if you call it, automatically should press a button( submit button). Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a flag in the source website either through GET or POST and have the destination website run the onClick() event of the Submit button by checking the Request.QueryString or Request.Form variable.

Comment: I have problems to understand it, Can you give me an example? If it is possible and you can do it eventuell for [link](https://www.adidas.de/superstar-schuh/EG4957.html) this side to click choose your size

Comment: <a href = "mywebsite.asp?flag=0or1">My Hyperlink</a> //This is a GET example for ASP. Check the flag value in the receiving form using Request.QueryString("flag")

Comment: When the Get or Post is not on the webiste i can't do it right?

Comment: The Get or Post is available in HTTP (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol) for transmitting information from website to website. You must be able to edit the source code of the transmitting website and the receiving website. If you use GET, you can attach the flag parameter to the transmitting website URL. Example: ```http://www.test.com/transmitwebpage.asp?flag=0``` Then in the receiving website you receive the transmitted variable by reading Response.QueryString("flag"). Use the flag value that has been read in the onClick() event of the Submit button.